# Hyperelliptic locus is a $K(\pi,1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, teichmuller-theory

It is said in many papers that the hyperelliptic locus $\mathcal{H}_g\subseteq \mathcal{M}_g$ is a $K(\pi,1)$. (in the sense of orbifolds). This is justified by saying that it can be constructed as an orbifold quotient of a contractible analytic subspace of the Teichmuller space by the hyperelliptic mapping class group. Apparently, this is "well-known from Teichmuller theory", but I can't find a precise reference (I am more of an algebraic geometer). Are you aware of a place where this is written up?

Comment: Let $X = (\mathbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,1,\infty\})^{d}$, where $d = \dim \mathcal{H}_g$. Let $U\subset X$ be the complement of the diagonals $\Delta_{ij}$. Then there is a finite etale morphism $U\to \mathcal{H}_g$  (in the category of algebraic stacks). Thus, don't we now  reduce to showing that $U$ is a $K(\pi,1)$?

Comment: Yes that is one way, but is it easy to see that $U$ is a $K(\pi,1)$? Most importantly, I was hoping for a proof that would simultaneously show that the orbifold fundamental group is the hyperelliptic mapping class group.

Comment: The space $U$ in Ariyan's comment is just $M_{0,2g+2}$. So it is a $K(\pi,1)$ because its universal cover is a Teichmuller space. One can also use this description to see that the fundamental group is the hyperelliptic mapping class group, given that the latter is a Z/2 central extension of the mapping class group of a sphere with 2g+2 unordered punctures.